# importing joomla user details into owncloud

Tags: mysql, joomla, owncloud

Based on the way Joomla! creates passwords within the db, is it possible to export user details from Joomla!, such as username, password, email address, and then import them into owncloud db, would this be possible, or are the encoding algorithms different for joomla and owncloud?